# Macro expansion issue in Mingw GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, c-preprocessor

```
#define A2W_EX(lpa, nChars) (\
    ((_lpa_ex = lpa) == NULL) ? NULL : (\
        _convert_ex = (lstrlenA(_lpa_ex)+1),\
        FAILED(::ATL::AtlMultiply(&_convert_ex, _convert_ex, static_cast<int>(sizeof(WCHAR)))) ? NULL : \
        ATLA2WHELPER(   \
            (LPWSTR)_ATL_SAFE_ALLOCA(_convert_ex, _ATL_SAFE_ALLOCA_DEF_THRESHOLD), \
            _lpa_ex, \
            _convert_ex / sizeof(WCHAR), \
            _acp_ex)))
```

I am copy-pasting some macros from Visual Studio int MingW and I am getting the following error

```
In member function 'ATL::CComVariant& ATL::CComVariant::operator=(LPCSTR)':
C:\.../atlconv.h:635:11: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
    (LPWSTR)_ATL_SAFE_ALLOCA(_convert_ex, _ATL_SAFE_ALLOCA_DEF_THRESHOLD), \
           ^
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Please post a compilable example that reproduces the problem.  It might be helpful to indicate exactly which distribution and version of MinGW you're using.

Comment: The error suggests that `LPWSTR` is not defined